# LRU Project on Java

Tags: java, spring, swing, lru

I had a project about LRU on Java. I used ArrayList to keep my Objects (which named Kisi), deleted the last Obj to set size of the ArrayList (to 5). I have finished but I wonder that is there any easier way to do this?

By the way I used swing and spring to create obj's.

There is a part of my code:

```
Kisi k = ctx.getBean("kisi", Kisi.class);
k.setName(textName.getText());
k.setSurname(textSurname.getText());

for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
//  if (k.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(liste.get(i).getName())
//  && k.getSurname().equalsIgnoreCase(liste.get(i).getSurname())) {
//      liste.remove(i);
//  }
    if(k.equals(liste.get(i))) {
        liste.remove(i);
    }
}

liste.add(0, k);
model.clear();

if (liste.size() == 6) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, liste.get(liste.size()-1)+" Silindi");
    liste.remove(liste.size()-1);
}

for (Kisi kisi : liste) {
    model.addElement(kisi);
}

textName.setText("");
textSurname.setText("");
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you to clearly explain what your code does and what is the goal you want to achieve. You want to move the element k from position x to 0, so that the Last Recently Used is in first position? What is `model`? Can you add the declaration of `model` and `liste`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop you are using to find the index of `k` object that matches your item in `liste` `ArrayList` could give better performance and readability if you use `indexOf` method instead.

That is:-

Instead of the for loop;

```
for (int i = 0; i < liste.size(); i++) {
//                  if (k.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(liste.get(i).getName())
//                          && k.getSurname().equalsIgnoreCase(liste.get(i).getSurname())) {
//                      liste.remove(i);
//              }
                    if(k.equals(liste.get(i))) {
                        liste.remove(i);

                    }
                }
```

I recommend you to simply do something like this;

```
liste.remove(liste.indexOf(k));
```

This returns -1 if k is not found in `liste`

You can use that return value instead of matching `liste.size() == 6`, if that suits your use case as well.

[Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

There may be other suggestions possible, but I guess more information will be required about your code as mentioned in the comments.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I assume with LRU you mean caching.

Here is an implementation using LinkedHashMap:

```
public class LRUCache<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int cacheSize;

    public LRUCache( int cacheSize )
    {
        super( cacheSize, 0.75f, true );
        this.cacheSize = cacheSize;
    }

    protected boolean removeEldestEntry( Map.Entry<K, V> eldest )
    {
        return size() >= cacheSize;
    }
}
```